# Deletar linha de acordo com a diferença de datas em MySQL

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, mysqli, delete

Estou tentando deletar linhas de uma tabela usando como referência a diferença entre a data atual e a data que a linha foi cadastrada. Aqui está meu código:

```
 DELETE FROM lixeira
 WHERE diferenca > 60 IN
 (
 SELECT DATEDIFF('2018-11-20',data_exclusao) AS diferenca
 FROM lixeira
 )
```

Sendo que "data_exclusao" é a coluna que armazena a data de cadastro dos dados da linha. Porém o console está me retornando o seguinte erro:

[image: Mensagem de erro]

Comment: Por que não chama o `datediff` direto no `where`? Algo como `where datediff(...) > 60`

Comment: Eu tentei, mas não estava apagando as linhas de acordo que eu queria, vou tentar novamente.

Comment: Confirme também os parâmetros da função na documentação, o tipo de retorno e o tipo das colunas envolvidas.

Comment: Deu certo, aparentemente era porque a coluna "data_exclusao" era DATETIME, mudei para DATE e deu certo, obrigado pelo alerta.